# redraw UITableView or UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a linechart in my `tableViewCells` that is drawn in a way, where I can't simply call a function to redraw it. So to redraw this chart I think I need to completely redraw the entire `tableView`.

The reason I need to redraw it, is that it's not responsive. So when I change the orientation of the device, the chart doesn't automatically adjust to it's new size.

I got a function calling when I change the orientation of my device. However I havn't been able to redraw my `UITableView`.

I've tried:

```
self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
tableView.setNeedsDisplay()
self.view.setNeedsLayout()
tableView.setNeedsLayout()
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

None of which seems to redraw my tableView, like it's drawn when the viewController is loaded.

I'm not using storyboards, and I'm using constraints.

Any help getting the full tableView or simply the lineChart to redraw would be greatly appreciated.

this is the library I used for my LineChart:
https://github.com/zemirco/swift-linechart

Comment: How about this 

selt.tableView.dataSource = nil ;
self.tableView.delegate = nil ;
self.tableView.reloadData()
self.tableView.dataSource = self ; // or whatever datasource you have 
self.tableView.delegate = self ; // or whatever delegate you have 
self.tableView.reloadData() ;

Comment: Try adding this line on top of the previous ones . 
while (  tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(<Your Cell Identifier>) !=nil ) { }

Comment: Tried adding it like this: `while ( tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("com.Formula.mySuggestionsCell") !=nil ) { }` But first there's an error saying "Expected ',' seperator", adding the comma presents another error: "!= is not a prefix or uniary operator"

Answer (score 0):

You need to Call `reloadData` instance method for redraw the cells. and for auto adjust UI, you need to use autoresizing mask for the table and view you are using for lines.

Comment: as mentioned in the post I already tried: `self.tableView.reloadData()` As for the autoresizing. First off I don't use storyboards so I have that set to false. And I'm using constraints. The size of the LineChart is being resized correctly. But the line inside it isn't being redrawn automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually setting the `UITableView` frame and then calling `reloadData`

Comment: can you elaborate on setting the frame? (I'm using constraints), this is all it should need:  `self.view.addConstraints(
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
                "V:|-8-[tableView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))` and a horizontal constraint to take the full width.